# How do I find/delete old knowledge article file attachments?

Tags: apex, knowledge, files, file-storage

We have knowledge articles that contain attachments (e.g. PDFs). Over time, we'll update the article and replace the attachment with a newer version.  It appears that old links to older attachments still work.  So, if a user saves a link to an old KB article attachment, they'll see the old doc.

We only want users to be able to retrieve the file associated with the "current" KB article.  How can I find and delete these old versions?

Comment: Is that my ans solves your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for those articles which is not latest version based on article ids. Refer 
[KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm#topic-title)

Use this object to:

- Query or search generically across multiple article types.
- Filter on a specific version.
- Update standard fields, those fields that are updateable, in draft versions.

> SOQL query

```
SELECT Title, IsLatestVersion, ArticleType, KnowledgeArticleId, PublishStatus, VersionNumber
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
WHERE PublishStatus='archived'
AND IsLatestVersion = false
AND KnowledgeArticleId = '***Insert article ID***'
```

After retrieval the list you can perform delete operation like this:

```
String articleId = '***Insert article ID***';
Integer versionNumber = 1;
KbManagement.PublishingService.deleteArchivedArticleVersion(articleId, versionNumber);
```

For more information, refer

> [PublishingService Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm) which uses the methods in the KbManagement.PublishingService class to manage the lifecycle of an article and its translations.

*You can change the query based on your need. I have tried to show pointer.*